# Using Git am when outlook is involved

Tags: git, email, outlook, git-patch, git-am

I am using linux in a virtual machine but my host is windows with outlook installed. Currently when I receive emails containing git patches they pop up in my outlook.

How do I apply these patches? They are not sent as attachments, they are sent presumably through git send mail.

Can I set up my VM to recieve them in the VM mailbox? (so far no success)

Can I save the patches to a folder in a git am friendly format? 
      so far i have been trying this angle, I thought, if I drag and drop the messages into a folder and then git am on that folder then it would work, however if i do this, outlook saves them as .msg instead of .eml and their doesnt seem to be a way to convert. I have tried save as text file but then i get either "Patch does not have a valid e-mail address" with git am or "trailing whitespace" with git apply. I am guessing that i could solve the whitespace issue by removing the windows line endings but it all seems a bit of a hack and as i am doing this as part of a commercial team i would like it to work properly.

-Thanks for any help, chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I came up with comes from here:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Outlook-to-Unix-Mailbox-2.html

There is an alternate method on the next page, but I found this was relatively hassle free and not to painful to use on a semi-regular basis.

**Pre-requists**

- install Thunderbird on your windows machine
- when you open it, choose "skip integration"
- have a shared folder set up on your VM machine

**Method**

- Receive the patch emails in outlook
- you may want to put them in a folder / filter
- Open Thunderbird
- Click the 3 lines in the top right -> Tools -> Import
- Choose "Mail"
- Choose "Outlook"
- You will now have a folder with a name like "Outlook Import1"
- In that you will have all your outlook email, in folders just like outlook
- select all the patch emails, right-click->Save As-> choose your shared folder, click "select folder"
- At this point you will have  ***proper***  .eml files in your shared folder (instead of the .msg files that outlook would produce)
- at this point you can run '''git am  - ''' on that folder to apply all the patches

**Possible Improvements***

- There is a possibility that if we created a shared folder to where the imports are saved we could use git AM on that, however that has not been successful for me yet and is a little more voodoo then i like.
- This might be easier if we used Thunderbird instead of outlook, but i am not sure if that would be possible with Microsoft exchange.
- If we had a script that converted .msg files to  ***proper***  .eml files (with headers), we could remove the need for thunderbird, [apparently there are unix tools for this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282691/how-to-convert-msg-file-outlook-email-msg-into-eml)
  **The question is**, would they be  ***proper***  .eml files??